# Can Perspective be used to improve conversations?

Tags: discussion, behavior, rude-or-abusive

I just found a nice tool called [Perspective](https://www.perspectiveapi.com/), which shows if what you are writing, will be perceived as rude or offensive. From their product description:

> Perspective is an API that makes it easier to host better conversations. The API uses machine learning models to score the perceived impact a comment might have on a conversation. Developers and publishers can use this score to give realtime feedback to commenters or help moderators do their job, or allow readers to more easily find relevant information, as illustrated in two experiments below. We’ll be releasing more machine learning models later in the year, but our first model identifies whether a comment could be perceived as “toxic" to a discussion.

Maybe it could improve the quality of questions, answers and comments if something like that would be shown to the user.

Comment: Looks interesting - although I'm not sure we here really have much of the problems major media outlets' comments sections have. The kind of stuff that is *easy* to detect as offensive is quickly removed as it is. Our real problems are arguably more in the subtle areas of tone where no API can help

Comment: Simply looking at some of the examples that they're showing on that page right now it's showing plenty of inappropriate content as "good content" simply because it's not swearing at people.  And of course something like that can't consider context, which makes it not particularly useful for a site like SO.

Comment: We have request an api key for [HeatDetector](http://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat) a week ago, but no response yet, lets see it would be interesting to test.

Comment: To follow on what Servy said, even if [you run Stack Overflow comments past humans](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/31/the-hunting-of-the-snark/), the lack of context can lead them to identify comments as being rude when they really aren't or labeling noisy comments as good just because they said "thanks". However, comments aren't subject to the same review as normal posts, so even having something that just identified clear insults could still catch many that are missed.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about using this tool to mark comments as offensive, but rather to let the user that is writing the comment rethink if what he is writing could be missunderstood. I wasn't thinking about trolls. It may be useful for people (like me), which don't have english as their primary language. I have often found that people which obviously do not talk english that well, often post rude comments (imho without knowing that they are being rude)

Comment: Hah, it labeled "LMGTFY" as "34% similar to comments people said were "toxic".

Comment: @Servy - Most of the comments with insults disappear when you move the slider until the icon is a blue circle.

Comment: @BSMP That just filters the comments shown to only show the ones it thinks are "good".  All I was saying was that, of the ones that it thinks are "good", there were plenty of rude comments.

Comment: `but rather to let the user that is writing the comment rethink if what he is writing could be missunderstood` I'd be *very* surprised if the API could predict that with meaningfully good success - but you never know I guess.

Comment: Single data point: when I test the comment texts from the only significant clash I've had with moderators on SE over rudeness - where I was rather upset by [UXSE mods changing the wording of a comment of mine](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/mod-edited-my-comment-and-made-it-ruder) in a way that turned purely technical criticism of an answer into a bizarre moral attack on the poster that claimed that they were behaving "inappropriately" and "unjustifiably" by advancing an argument I disagreed with - Perspective thoroughly agrees with the mods on which version was ruder.

Comment: Getting any idea of whether this tool can be useful to us would require somehow getting a large sample of comments that have inadvertently caused angry conflicts due to needlessly inflammatory wording, plus a sample of comments that are widely agreed to be polite but *are also robust technical criticism*, and confirming that Perspective considers the former to be rude and the latter polite. How to go about acquiring those samples is a hard problem that I have no answer to, but without someone doing such science I don't think I'll have any belief that Perspective will work for us.

Comment: Wow, the page demo is extremely awful. It shows how censorship can change global warming from "something incredibly stupid to do" to "climate change doesn't exist or influence me".

Comment: I wouldn't totally trust it. It says that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6898452/4284627) is more "toxic" than [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAYhj.png), which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @DonaldDuck but the question contained the word "stupid"! Surely that means it must be rude, right? Right?

Comment: "Hey guys, I think this is super cool. My friends said I was an asshole, but you're different, you're great." 66% said toxic. The tool is a neat idea but it's not close for production.

Comment: @TankorSmash I don't think it's even a good idea.  IIRC, their data is crowdsourced, which means it won't be applicable to a technical site like this anyway

Comment: Yeah, I think what @MarkAmery said is correct. It's somewhat biased towards the word [stupid](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36301972#36301972). (Perspective approved the key and whitelisted our app yesterday, we began testing it soon after that)

Answer (score 39):

I'm professionally active in Machine Learning, and I've seen many proposals in a similar phase. That is to say: nowhere near production-ready. "Perspective" is basically an academic exercise at this point.

This isn't just my opinion, [others](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/603735/its-easy-to-slip-toxic-language-past-alphabets-toxic-comment-detector/) have observed the same.

The main problem IMO is that there are many forms of toxic content:

- There's the intentionally toxic content. Filters don't help, because Perspective is too easily worked around.
- There are unintentional mistakes, but those are typically not caused by specific bad words. Instead, these might be caused by e.g. ambiguous references ("that's bad" where it's not clear what "that" refers to). Perspective doesn't understand grammar at all, and misses this too. (This seems to be what Daniel hinted at in his first comment).
- Then there are toxic comments by indirection, where it's the content of a link which makes a comment toxic. Again, Perspective will miss that.

Comment: It does have a rudimentary understanding of grammar. However as you've said; it's still not as advanced as it would potentially need to be and is still very much an alpha build. It's not production ready.

Answer (score 1):

[Perspectitve](https://www.perspectiveapi.com/) white-listed our community developt stackapp [HeatDetector](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat) and we are sending all SO comments through the api.

Currently we are only at the beginning and still need information if we need to pre-process (remove html ecc.) comments before sending them to API.

We have seen that the API also provides a method for feed-back, hence teaching the system. However before implementing this we will need speak to SE since the comment is stored by perspective (maybe we will make a meta or just ping a Community Manager).

For now it's mostly fun, we are outputting in chat everything that has a threshold >0.5 but I think with some further development, feedback ecc, it will surely help us to catch some nasty stuff and keep SO nice for future users.

Comment: "we will need speak to SE since the comment is stored by perspective" AFAIK comments are cc-by-sa too, so as long as Perpective acknowledge from where the content came from, it's alright.